# How to draw lines from point-to-point, In PostGIS / PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have some GPS points in PostGIS, and I’m looking for a way to draw lines from point to point, to illustrate travel routes.

I know how to do one long line, but I need to do small point-to-point lines.

I have a table of GPS points, from tracking a group of vehicles. It looks like this:

```
dtt                |id   |geom                                         |
-------------------+-----+---------------------------------------------+
2021-03-12 00:00:00|13116|POINT (4.428372016319861 0.6945075255173904) |
2021-03-12 00:00:01|91665|POINT (4.189513573279748 0.9352590120755709) |
2021-03-12 00:00:01|14532|POINT (4.211658477783203 1.152058821458083)  |
2021-03-12 00:00:01|16531|POINT (4.396507263183594 0.6196146011352539) |
2021-03-12 00:00:01|17655|POINT (4.452470926138071 0.7759194007286658) |
…
```

Columns are PostgreSQL types: timestamp, integer and PostGIS Point, restively.

I have +10 mill points per day and need to analyse 6 months’ worth of data, and potentially 5-10 years of historical data later.

Each vehicle has from 1 to ca. 20.000 points per day.

I have reduced the number of points to only one per hour, since that fits my analysis goal, and greatly reduces the number of point. I do that like this:

```
    -- table with mini-points, and only one per hour, per id
    drop table if exists dmaais.selgeohour cascade;
    create table dmaais.selgeohour as
      select distinct on (date_trunc('hour', dtt), id) *
        from dmaais.selgeo
          order by date_trunc('hour', dtt), id, dtt
    ;
```

I would like to draw lines, between the hour-point, to represent vehicles movements, i.e. only lines between points from same vehicle, and drawn in time-order.

So far I have tried this: (based on the online help for [ST_MakeLine](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html))

```
     -- draw lines from point-to-point, attributing with temporal and spatial distance
    drop table if exists dmaais.selline cascade;
    create table dmaais.selline as
      SELECT gps.id, ST_MakeLine(gps.geom ORDER BY gps.dtt) as geom, 
             ST_Length(ST_MakeLine(gps.geom ORDER BY gps.dtt)) as leng,
             EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (max(gps.dtt) - min(gps.dtt))) as dura
        FROM dmaais.selgeohour As gps
          GROUP BY id
    ;
```

As my data are in geo-coordinates the ‘leng’ fields measures the length in degrees, which is not optimal. But it is a good-enough approximation for distance for my purpose, and calculation speed is important, so I don’t want to include any geo-transformation at this stage.

The ‘dura’ field gives the travel time in seconds, and that is what I seek.

[image: Result data, so far.]

This result is not completely different from what I want, but it creates one long line, representing the entire route of the individual vehicle.

How do I get separate line between each pair of points, and the fields ‘leng’ and ‘dura’ to represent the length and duration of traveling only between these two point?

Comment: Do you know the `LAG()` and `LEAD()` functions ? Maybe they can help you. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html

Comment: Will look at LAG() and LEAD() windows functions. Can you point at any good example use?

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/, so you can create `make_line` with the previous record. The `LEAD` function is with the next record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get multiple segments for each ID, you can't group by ID.

Instead, you can use a window function to partition by ID, order by ddt and at last to access the following row

```sql
with src (id, dtt, geom) as (values (1,1,'point(1 1)'),(1,2,'point(1 2)'),(1,3,'point(1 3)'),(2,1,'point(2 1)'),(2,2,'point(2 2)'),(2,3,'point(1 3)'))
SELECT id, dtt, 
      st_asText(
        st_makeLine(geom, lead(geom) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dtt))) 
FROM src;

 id | dtt |      st_astext
----+-----+---------------------
  1 |   1 | LINESTRING(1 1,1 2)
  1 |   2 | LINESTRING(1 2,1 3)
  1 |   3 |
  2 |   1 | LINESTRING(2 1,2 2)
  2 |   2 | LINESTRING(2 2,1 3)
  2 |   3 |
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the commnt from @J. Monticolo I have created this that do exactely what I want.

I can't mark a comment as accepted answer, so I'll accept th ansver from JGH, which is similar, but came while I was coding.

```
-- draw lines from point-to-point, attributing with temporal and spatial distance...  ver. 1.1
drop table if exists dmaais.sellegs cascade;
create table dmaais.sellegs as
  with step as (
    select dtt, 
           id, 
           ST_MakeLine(geom, LEAD(geom,1) over (partition by id order by id, dtt)) as geom,
           extract(EPOCH from (LEAD(dtt,1) over (partition by id order by id, dtt) - dtt)) as dura
      from dmaais.selgeohour )
  select *,
         ST_Length(geom) as leng,
         (ST_Length(geom) / step.dura) *60 *60*60 as speed
         -- 60 to go from degrees to arc-minutes, 
         -- and 60*60 to go from seconds to hour.
         -- Arc-minutes/hour is almost like knots 
    from step
;
```